# PyMongo with Multiprocessing Pool in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, multiprocessing, pymongo, pool

I have a problem I'm struggling with for weeks.

```
def doSomething(item):
   client = MongoClient(DB_CONNECTION_STRING, maxPoolSize=100000, connect=False)
   dbclient = client.mydb

   try:
       getAWebpage()
   except MyException as e:
      client.close()
      # I know that the recursion here could cause problems, but this is not the point
      doSomething(item)
   else:
      # do something with the web page and save in the DB
      dbclient.collection.insertone({...})
      ...
      client.close()

def singleTask(item):
   doSomething(item)
   time.sleep(0.3)

def startTask(list, threads=10):
   pool = ThreadPool(threads)
   results = pool.map(singleTask, list)
   pool.close()
   pool.join()

   return results
```

I see in the MongoDB log that it opens a lot of connections without closing them and at a certain point MongoDB stops accepting connections, crashing everything.

What is wrong with this code? I can't really understand.
I know that the recursion could cause problem with the overall code but I'm first trying to solve this problem.

Any help will be much appreciated! Thank you

Comment: why is your maxpoolsize so high?

Comment: I just tried everything, so I tried also to put the maxPoolSize so high 